# How to unlock Proficient Level

Tags: empire-defense-2

How do I unlock difficulty levels higher than `Skilled`? DO I need to get more stars or do I need to buy specific generals or soldiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unlock higher levels by clearing every map in the highest level. So if you want to play the hero level, you need to play through the campaign twice.